# Is something considered idolatry even if it doesn't acknowledge a deity outside of Hashem?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, avodah-zarah, sin

> **G-d grant me the serenity to accept the things I cannot change; courage to change the things I can; and wisdom to know the
>   difference.**

The above listed prayer is known as the **Serenity Prayer**. It's actually a prayer that was made famous by A.A. (Alcoholics Anonymous) as something people recite within their **Twelve Step Program.**

My question is regarding the concept of idolatry.

The above prayer makes no mention of Jesus Christ. The above prayer makes no question of a religion outside of Judaism. The above prayer is simply a call for guidance from G-d.

If a Jew said the above prayer but they said it with their heart and mind and spirit with Hashem in mind, is that Idolatry?

Comment: Idolatry is a precise sin. The can/cannot dialectic is not subtil enough for a jew prayer.

Comment: Why would this be idolatry? Jews are certainly allowed to pray to God

Comment: If I wrote this prayer, would you recite it simply on the grounds that I am a Jew? I see nothing wrong with this prayer that you would not be allowed to say it. It makes no mention of any other diety thab G-d Himself.

Comment: @DoubleAA Isn't there a problem with praying by the words of a non-Jew, particularly if he is an idol worshiper?

Comment: @SAH If there is, a source would greatly improve this question.